# Shortcut to select all children of a game object

Tags: unity

I want to click on a game object and select all of its children. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a shortcut, but you can write an editor script to do this if it's really that much of a hassle to shift select a bunch of children

there is an example here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1773802/how-can-i-select-whole-object-with-its-childrens-i.html

however, the functionality here may need to be fine-tuned, as it recursively grabs all children which you may not want. I am also not confident in the script's ability to select multiple parents and then grab their children.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing it in the hierarchy, you can just right click the object and click the "Select Children" option.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold `Shift Key` and `left click` on the `first child` and `last child` to select all the children in middle.

Answer (score -2):

Hold shiftKey and select first and last child

Comment: This seems to be the same advice that Rajas shared in another answer over a year ago. What new insight are you aiming to add here?